# Extracting "Last updated by" property of a word file

Tags: c#, ms-word, file-properties

I am making an application in which I need to keep a check on all the properties of a word file like Last Updated,Name etc
I also need Last Updated by, i.e the user who made changes in the file.
How can I get this information?

**EDIT**

This is what I am doing:
FileInfo[] wordFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc");
I am extracting other properties like this:

wordFiles. (and all the properties are listed but not the one i am looking for)
I am looking for some code in C# which can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenXML SDK. [Here](http://techdos.com/content/view/305/69/) is a good example on how to get the properties of a document.

Comment: He mentions *.DOC in the question, which would tend to indicate that he's trying to pull the info from a DOC file, which you can't open with the OPENXML SDK. But it's a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about DOC files, those are OLE compound documents, and you can read the properties directly via the OLE Compound document functions.

Here's a page that details opening and reading properties in C++

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186898

Comment: I want the code in C#. I am sorry I didn't get the code in that link